# Oja rule incorrect principal components (PCs)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, matlab, feature-selection

I am trying to get sequentially PCs from Oja's rule. But the error seems to increase with PCs, which shouldn't happen. Please let me know where the error, I can't seem to get it. I am initialising weight incorrectly and I can't find a reference as to what they should be compared to the learning rate.

The complete code for reproducing: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B16PrXUjs69zSkdBVGdUTmhlb2s&usp=sharing

demo_check.m

```
clear all;
clc;
load hald;
error_threshold=0.01;
pc=[];
train_data=feature_scale(hald);% feature scaling 
x=train_data;
d=5; %maximum no. of dimensions
for i=1:d,
    pc_i=oja(x');   %stores i^th principal component
    pc=[pc,pc_i ];  %pc matrix

    [residual,error]=getApproxError(x,pc,train_data); % gets the error at the present number  
                                    %of components                  
    if error <=error_threshold  % condition for breaking loop if error is 
                                        %less than threshold
        break
    end
    x =residual; 
   disp(sprintf('The error at iteration %d is %.2f',i,error));
end
```

getApproxError.m

```
function [residual,error] = getApproxError( train_data,pc,actual_train_data )
%% returns the error in dimension reduction
[m,n]=size(train_data);
train_reduced=train_data*pc;
train_approx=train_reduced*pc';
residual=actual_train_data-train_approx;
error=norm(actual_train_data-train_approx)/m;
end
```

Output

```
The error at pc 1 is 0.47
The error at pc 2 is 0.47
The error at pc 3 is 1.40
The error at pc 4 is 7.44
The error at pc 5 is 49.17
```

I am posted my question at stackoverflow also not being sure where it would fit.
Though, a bad practice I have posted my question at stackoverflow also not being sure where it would fit. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33312643/oja-rule-incorrect-pcs

The above example has 13x5 dimensions. (My actual dataset has 400 x153000 dimensions.)
Learning rate: .0001

Comment: Just a few questions to clarify the issue. How many data samples do you have? How many dimensions do you have for each sample? What is your learning rate (step) for the training procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Typical problem with OJA algorithm is that weight update is proportional to your input data. The more data samples and dimensions you have the less step for the training procedure you need. For the data sample 13x5 it seams like a good step equal to 0.0001, but it's not necessary a good value for your dataset. Before applying OJA algorithm in practice you should use two main rules.

1. Typically learning rate value should be very small value, maybe $10 ^ {-10}$ for dataset that contains a lot of values.
2. The most important one, you should normalize your data before apply algorithm. Update proportional to the data and your data scale make big influence in weight update procedure. Just a small example. I write it in Python, if you are not familiar with this language you can just check the outputs.

Here I create a random small dataset with 100 samples and 5 features.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.seed(0)
>>> data = np.random.randn(100, 5).round(2)
>>> data[:5, :]
array([[ 1.76,  0.4 ,  0.98,  2.24,  1.87],
       [-0.98,  0.95, -0.15, -0.1 ,  0.41],
       [ 0.14,  1.45,  0.76,  0.12,  0.44],
       [ 0.33,  1.49, -0.21,  0.31, -0.85],
       [-2.55,  0.65,  0.86, -0.74,  2.27]])
```

As you can see values are not so big. Below code shows that network converge for this data after a few epochs.

```
>>> from neupy import algorithms
>>> ojanet = algorithms.Oja(
...     minimized_data_size=2,
...     show_epoch=1,
...     verbose=True,
...     step=0.001
... )
>>> ojanet.train(data, epsilon=0.4, epochs=5)
Epoch 1
  * Train error:  1.9570632374143175
  * Validation error: -
  * Epoch time: 6e-05 sec
[TRAIN] Epoch #4 stopped. Network converged.
Epoch 4
  * Train error:  0.6286118230141841
  * Validation error: -
  * Epoch time: 2e-05 sec
[TRAIN] End train
```

And now exactly the same code, but now before train the network I multiply all dataset values by 10.

```
>>> ojanet = algorithms.Oja(
...     minimized_data_size=2,
...     show_epoch=1,
...     verbose=True,
...     step=0.001
... )
>>> ojanet.train(10 * data, epsilon=0.4, epochs=5)
Epoch 1
  * Train error:  34.65695767082828
  * Validation error: -
  * Epoch time: 0.00012 sec
[TRAIN] Epoch #4 stopped. Network didn't converge after 4 iterations
Epoch 4
  * Train error:  9.847792502904135e+53
  * Validation error: -
  * Epoch time: 4e-05 sec
[TRAIN] End train
```

Just a small multiplication operation makes error blow up.

How much do you need to decrease your learning rate and in what range should be your values in dataset you should decide depend on problem. Usually you should choose some not very small values and decrease them by some fraction until your network start train in a valid way.

Comment: Thanks for awesome reply! With respect to what you said I also wanted to ask if how you intialise weights has any effect on the oja's rule? The package you used seems to use normal distribution(https://github.com/itdxer/neupy/blob/master/neupy/algorithms/associative/oja.py#L102).

Comment: My dataset size is `400x153600`, what do you think should be a good learning rate? Also, what is safe number for the iterations?

Comment: Weight anitialization should be random and values don't need to be very big as well. Basically you should make kind of a mix between small values in dataset, learning rate and weights. I'm not sure that it will work for a big datasets. If you set up parameters to small they will vanish results and your outputs would be near zero and the same will slow up your weight update procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!!  Also, thanks for the info. abt the python package I didn't knew about it before. I tried for my dataset and it seemed to run into memory issues, which is weird. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33336176/crashing-ram-using-memmap-in-oja-rule Have you tried on large datasets?